# Placement for image credits/ acknowledgements for homepage banners

Tags: website-design

What is the best place to add in the image credits? Is it appropriate to have text on the banner itself. We have a carousel on the homepage with 4 stock images.

Any examples would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The credit texts are always a nuisance, I would try to pass as unnoticed as possible.

A solution can be in an invisible line of text at the bottom of each image and a hover effect so that it appears when placing the mouse over it.

[image]

Comment: this is a technical solution for the problem. but I don't think it is in accordance with most of the image licenses. so please read your license carefully. Perhaps you could write a short note (hover for image credit) to show good will. Or "see page XY for image credits" if you cannot implement such things in your carousel.

Answer (score 1):

Users don't care about who made the image or from which platform you licensed the image from, so try to find a place where only lawyers or copyright holders would go for (for example the imprint site).

Placing credits on the banner or below the banner just adds visual clutter.

But some image agencies state that you need to place the credits on the same place where the image is placed, so this highly depends on the source you are getting the credits for.